# How to add page number into multiple layout for one report form(.rdf) in Oracle reports

Tags: plsql, oraclereports

I have problem to put the page number  layout for one report form(.rdf) in Oracle reports. i have design more than one layout but i want to display the page number with the different title in one form.
For example i have 4 design layout. The layout 1 have title A, layout 2 have title B,layout 3 have title C and  layout 4 have title D. The problem is i don't know how to insert page number in diffrent page.
Anyone know about this?

This is my pictures
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try,

- for page number --> `&<PhysicalPageNumber>`
- for total page  --> `&<TotalPages>`

Comment: ok.i have put the group for page number and total page in repeating frame in my report.Tq very much. it was successful.:)